# dynamically change the appcache

Tags: php, html, caching

I want to dynamically change the .appcache file for every user that visits the website.

To do this I'm using php to generate the file.

cache.php

```
<?php
//set the header in the hope that that would work
header("Content-Type: text/cache-manifest");
$sid = session_id();
echo '
CACHE MANIFEST
generated at: '.date('Y-m-d').'

/cah/index.php
/cah/</code>

CACHE:
/css/somecssfile.css
/fonts/somefont.woff2
/js/somejs.js
/cash.php
/get.php?something&sessionid='.$sid.'
/favicon.ico

NETWORK:
*
    ';
?>
```

In this case the javascript would get something from get.php and send over the sessionid so someone else couldn't easily create a bot to for example delete someone's account.

but if I try to load this by putting

```
<html manifest="../cash.php">
```

in the html it would give this error.

Application Cache Error event: Failed to parse manifest https://example.com/cash.php

Does someone know a fix or is this just impossible.

PS.
As to why you would do this. If you have a website in multiple languages you don't want to cache every language you just want to cache the language that the user selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how I put

```
echo '
CACHE MANIFEST
etc.
```

at the beginning. Apparently you can't have an enter at the beginning of you appcache file. so changing it to:

```
echo 'CACHE MANIFEST
etc.
```

works.